# How do I shape my pecs?

Tags: weightlifting

I have unusually shaped pecs - they are round, nearly pointed.  In my youth, I used to do a lot of pushups.  Now, I am doing weight training and do presses, inclined presses and flys but my pecs are still rounded and oddly shaped.  Are there exercises that can build and square off the outside of my pecs?

I am a 28 year old male in decent shape with low body-fat.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, pics would help.

Answer (score 2):

Muscle shape is determined by genetics. Not quite sure where/what you want squared off, but wider-grip stuff seems to target the "outside" edge (for me, could be because I'm weak, too :) so possibly incline/decline work with a wide grip.

Answer (score 1):

#### Gynecomastia

*"Round pecs that are nearly pointed"* sounds like [Gynecomastia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gynecomastia). Unfortunately if that's the case surgery is the only reliable treatment. You can talk with a doctor, specifically an Endocrinologist, and see if they would recommend some type of [hormonal treatment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gynecomastia#Treatment). Losing bodyfat might help but if there is significant gland development that won't go down with bodyfat reduction.

[image]

#### Other causes

If you do not have Gynecomastia then reducing your bodyfat and developing your pecs will change their shape. Don't get me wrong, you can't change how the actual muscle looks beyond making it bigger/smaller but the combination of muscle development/bodyfat does give it a different appearance.